# How to save single property change in core data leaving other changes unsaved?

Tags: ios, core-data

I was making an application which has a form to be filled and all changes where going into the main object context and are saved when user presses the final save button.

Everything was working fine until we got a change requesting us to add a feature for remarks in a few screens, for which I added remarks as a string attribute in the respective entities.

Now if I make some changes in the screen and add a remark, click on the save 
button for the remark, I should be able to save the remark irrespective of whether I save rest of the changes or not.

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just save it whether the rest property is set or not.

1. Fetch it(if not exist you need to alloc and init a new one).
2. Modify it.
3. Save it.

Comment: I will be saving the context. right ? If I save the context other chnages in the context will also get saved.

Comment: Yes. I think you can just don't change properties that you don't want to save before you save your remark. Modify those changes after you have saved your remark.

Comment: where do Keep the chnages till the final save/cancel is done ? I was thinking of storing everything in an array of blocks which I will execute later.